# div.my-class vs. .my-class any benefits?

Tags: html, css

If I am to only use this class on a div. Is there any benefit to using the first over the second?

```
div.my-class

.my-class
```

Comment: What kinds of benefits are you looking for? The first selector has a greater specificity than the second and only targets divs. Other than that I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Without a clear problem to be solved, answered or addressed this is purely opinion-based (and so off-topic) And, frankly, it depends on whether you explicitly want to style all elements with that class, or only `<div>` elements with that class, which is the only difference between the two selectors.

Comment: How do you know you won't use it on a non-div in the same/different context in future?

Comment: Besides theoretically making it easier for the browser to match the selector, the only benefit of adding the tag name would be reuse of the classname

Comment: **div.my-class** is just for div elements. **.my-class** is for everything with that class, so p.myclass and div.myclass will both be governed by it.

Comment: @j08691 Then an appropriate answer from you would be a simple "no". Why over complicate things...

Comment: How am I over-complicating things? I'm simply asking what you're question is. As several others have pointed out it's not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main benefit are that you can override other styles mentioned further down a CSS file by the laws of specificity: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Take this example: https://jsfiddle.net/uuav5c5s/

```
<div class="test">
    Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.test {
  color: red;
}
.test {
  color: green;
}
```

In my example, the color of the text in `.test` will be red, even though I've tried to override it further down the line...

On the flip side, a downside of using the element alongside the class itself is that if you try appending the `.test` class to a `<p>` element, thew styles won't apply...

Comment: Brilliant, perfect answer.